# casperJS css selectors: waitFor function always times out

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, casperjs

I am writing an automated login test and want to assert that I've logged into the page succesfully, and then take a screenshot of the page.

The DOM I am trying to acces looks like this:

```
<div class="form-group hidden-xs">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left logged-menu"> <strong class="pull-left"><font><font>Welcome,</font></font> </strong> 
        <li>
            <a href="/usuario"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
                <span class="hidden-xs">
                    <font><font class="">tocijan</font></font> 
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="btn-group balance">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">
                    <span id="balance_info">
                        <font>
                            <font>$ 178,345.79</font>
                        </font>
                    </span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">
                        <font>
                            <font>Toggle Dropdown</font>
                        </font>
                    </span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li>
                        <font>
                            <font>Bonus:</font>
                        </font>
                        <span id="hdnBonus">
                            <font>
                                <font>$ 0.00</font>
                            </font>
                        </span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li>
                        <font>
                            <font>Extractable:</font>
                        </font>
                        <span id="real_info">
                            <font>
                                <font>$ 178,345.79</font>
                            </font>
                        </span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li>
                        <font>
                            <font>Reserved Bonus:</font>
                        </font>
                        <span id="resbon_info">
                            <font>
                                <font>$ 100.00</font>
                            </font>
                        </span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/LoginPartial/Logoff?n2page=466&amp;n2part=799"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></i>
                <font>
                    <font>Get out</font>
                </font>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clr"></div>
</div>
```

I want to assert that this element:

```
<a href="/usuario"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i><span class="hidden-xs"><font><font class="">tocijan</font></font></span></a>
```

Has the innerHTML (or text) of `tocijan`.

I've written my wait for function like this, but it always times out:

```
//waitfor function
this.waitFor(function check() {
    //evaluate if the page has a link to the user profile
    return this.evaluate(function() {
      return document.querySelector('a[href="/usuario"] span font font').innerHTML == 'tocijan';
    });
},
//after the condition is met
function then() {
    //capture a test image of the page
    this.capture('test.png');
});
```

I know that I log in, since I just implemented a basic wait for 10 sec timeout and took a screenshot of the page, and it was showing the correct result, but now I want to assert this with the waitFor function.

I am using the wrong css selectors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the time there is whitespace, because we as developers love our indentation. Try to check if the element is contained in the HTML:

```
return document.querySelector('...').innerHTML.indexOf('tocijan') != -1;
```

---

If this doesn't work, check if the element is in an iframe. You would need to specifically switch to iframes with `casper.withFrame()`.

Comment: you were correct, the whole <html> tag is in an iFrame that I failed to notice :)